# polymer not working or displaying no elements

Tags: polymer, element

Trying to display hello world using elements but nothing happens any help?

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">

  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="elements/hello-world.html">
 </head> 
<body unresolved>
<hello-world></hello-world>
</body>
</html>
```

hello-world.html

```html
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="hello-world" nonscript>
 <template>
   <h2>Hello World</h2>
 </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 2):

Code for "hello-world.html" is now:

```
  <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
 <dom-module id="hello-world">
 <template>
 <h1>Hello World</h1> 
</template>
 <script>
 Polymer ({ is: "hello-world", }); 
</script>
 </dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using polymer version 0.8 or 0.9, then `<polymer-element ...` should be `<dom-module ...`

See more from polymer site:

https://www.polymer-project.org/0.9/docs/start/quick-tour.html

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, nonscript needs to be noscript.

```
<polymer-element name="hello-world" noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and dont find the mistake.

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Polymer-Application</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!--<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
        <!-- file is available, auto completed by api -->

        <link rel="import" href="hello/hello.html">
        <!-- file is available, auto completed by api -->
        <!-- netbeans doesn't know relation import -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My first Polymer-Application</h1>
        <hello></hello>
    </body>
</html>
```

hello/hello.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<!-- file is available, auto complete by api -->
<polymer-element name="hello" noscript>
    <template>
        <h1>Hello Polymer world</h1>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

My platfrom is:

- Win 8.1
- nodejs
- bower
- polymer (installed over bower, folders and files are availible)
- git
- netbeans dev edition (as editor)
- xammp (as apache webserver)

tested with chrome, firefox and ie10 and the custom element is not be shown. i don't think it's a browser problem. it's the simpliest element you can write, but why did it not work?

Edit:

tested it on a clean ubuntu installation. and it still does not work?
i also tested original code from the polymer page and this won't work too.
am i to stupid for copy paste?

Edit 2:

i found it an have running my polymer apps. If i use Polymer 1.0.9 i should not read the tutorial for 0.5.0

changes:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <script scr="bower_components/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <!-- the lite edition is needet since polymer version 0.8 -->
    <link rel="import" href="hello/hello.html">
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <hello></hello>
  </body>
</html>
```

hello/hello.html:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="hello">
  <!-- its not longer a polymer-element. we have to use dom-module and id and the noscript option is not longer supported -->
  <template>
  <template>
  <script>
    // everytime you need to initialize a Polymer object
    Polymer({
      is: 'hello' // must be set now
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

if you want to work with parameters you need to set it in the polymer ready function and every placeholder must be surrounded by a html tag like span without any other content in it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line

```
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
```

This should fix the issue.