# Polymer - 404 Not Found

Tags: polymer

so I'm trying to write a simple hello world page using Polymer. The problem I'm having is whenever I run the `#polymer serve` command and load up my webpage it can't find the `webcomponents.min.js` and the `iron-component-page.html`. Any reason as to why this is happening and how can I fix it?

[image]

index.html

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>polymer-element</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="../webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="../iron-component-page/iron-component-page.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <iron-component-page src="polymer-element.html"></iron-component-page>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried some of the answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30277272/polymer-not-working-or-displaying-no-elements) but still can't get it to work.

Comment: Um, maybe the URLs in your index.html are wrong? Like try `bower_components/iron-component-page/iron-component-page.htm`?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't quite figured it yet but polymer is using polyserve under the hood, and I think that tries to be clever with url to file directory mapping.  I think it assumes a directory structure where you are developing a re-usable component so after complete when your element also sits in bower_components, you go ../web-component/web-component.html to find the import, but your development structure has bower_components within the directory you are actually developing your component in.

When dealing with an app, I just put "bower_components" at the route of my app directory, and my elements in the "src" directory as a subdirectory of that.  Then I explicitly use `/bower_components/web-component/web-component.html` in my html imports.

Running polymer serve from the root of your app then serves that at `localhost:8080/`

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: Assuming your working dir is "x" and components are in "x/components" , create a soft link thus:

`$ ln -s components bower_components`

**Long answer**:

polymer serve does not seem to read/honor .bowerrc.

My components directory is "components" under which all my polymer components are present.

> .bowerrc --> { "directory":"components"}

Running "polymer serve" starts the server, but when I navigate to "http://localhost:8000/index.html", I get a blank page.

Upon inspecting the network traffic in the browser, all requests to webcomponentjs* are returning 404s.

So.. `polymer serve` is not honoring a non-default components directory. It is expecting `bower-components` dir.